# ambiance-dark theme not working on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, themes, ambiance

Back at Ubuntu 14.04, I used ambiance-dark theme, and when I updated to 16.04 I could not install it with the usual way I used to employ in previous versions of Ubuntu, the commands I used are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ambiance-dark
```

And when I used them now it shows me:

```
sudo apt-get install ambiance-dark  

Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package ambiance-dark
```

Comment: There are no packages candidates, so contact the repository maintainer?

Answer (score 4):

add ppa to the repo as normal, do not update the repo. Go into system settings>software & updates>other software.

There you'll need to edit the ppa both main & source. Where you see Distribution, change it from 'Xenial' to 'Trusty'.

Now in terminal run,

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install ambience-dark
```

I tried & it worked.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Or;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes 
sudo apt update
```

You have already done above, use `ambiance-blackout-colors` instead;

```
sudo apt install ambiance-blackout-colors
```

Preview; 
[image: ambiance-blackout-aqua]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try ambience-colors themes as described [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/03/ambiance-radiance-colors-theme-suite.html).